# django datatables manytomany field serverside processing

Tags: python, django, django-models, datatables, django-datatable

In my Django project, I am using the datatables.net jquery plugin to display some of the data from my Django models in a table. I am using [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/) to do the serverside processing. Everything works well, but I have to display some data from another table that is linked to the first table using Django's manytomany field.
Currently it shows 'appname.Location.None' in every row of the datatable.

**models**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200000, blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    long = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    types = models.CharField(max_length=500000, blank=True, null=True)
    impact = models.CharField(max_length=500000, blank=True, null=True)
    loc = models.ManyToManyField(to=Location, related_name='loc', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views**

```
class events(BaseDatatableView):
    columns = ['name', 'status', 'impact', 'types', 'id', 'loc']
    order_columns = ['name', 'status', 'impact', 'types', 'id', 'loc']

    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#tableid').DataTable({
                                "processing": true,
                                "serverSide": true,
                                "ajax": "{% url 'evnts' %}",  //goes to class evnts
                                columns: [
                                    {
                                        data: 'name',                                        
                                    },
                                    {
                                        data: 'status',                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        data: 'impact',                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        data: 'types',                                   
                                    },
                                    {
                                        data: 'id',                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        data: 'loc'
                                    }
                                ]
                            });
                        });
```

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my views a bit and the script a bit and I could get it to work.

**views**

```
class events(BaseDatatableView):
    columns = ['name', 'status', 'impact', 'types', 'id', 'loc']
    order_columns = ['name', 'status', 'impact', 'types', 'id', 'loc']

    def get_initial_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        def prepare_results(self, qs):
        data = []
        for item in qs:
            loc = []
            for loca in item.loc.all():
                loc.append(loca.location)
            loc = ' '.join(loc)
            data.append([
                item.name,
                item.status,
                item.impact,
                item.types,
                item.id,
                loc
            ])
        return data
```

i have to replace `columns` with

```
columnDefs: [
                                    {
                                        targets: '0',
                                        name: 'name',                                       

                                    },
                                    {
                                        targets: '1',
                                        name: 'status',                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        targets: '2',
                                        name: 'impact',                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        targets: '3',
                                        name: 'types',                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        targets: '4',
                                        name: 'id',
                                    },
                                    {
                                        targets: '5',
                                        name: 'loc',                                      
                                    }
                                ]
```

in my **scripts**
and the **targets** refers to the class names of `<th>` tag of the table.
**Example**

```
<th class="0">Name</th>
```